# (Puppeteer) How to intercept HTTP request and send it again multiple times with a different body?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

So, what I want to achieve is to go to a page, intercept its calls and then send the same call multiple times with a different body.
Something like this

```js
 await page.setRequestInterception(true)

page.on('request', async (request) => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'image') request.abort()
    else {

        if (request.url().includes('query')) {
            //change page number in body because this is a paged query
            for (let pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < 100; pageNumber++) {
                //change body to include new 'pageNumber'
                //send request and await it
                //I am stuck here
            }

        }

        request.continue()

    }
})
```

But I don't know how can I change the body of the `request` object and **resend** it.

Basically, the query I am trying to call is a paged query which contains a `pageNumber` in its body, but when the page is loaded the call is only sent for `pageNumber = 0` and I'm trying to get the other pages as well.

Comment: I doubt it would be possible this way. `page.setRequestInterception` gives you ability to intercept requests which are made by the page. In this case you want to initiate requests which are not made by the page. To better understand your usecase, is it not possible to actually call `page.goto` multiple times with different page numbers and then process the responses received (and may be not using the interceptions at all)?

Comment: @yeniv, I had this idea as well. So basically reload the same page multiple times and change the `pageNumber` each time so that it loads a different page. This works but it is slow in my opinion. I also tried going to the page manually and then in Chrome Devtools,  I copied the request as a `fetch` request, and then use the same fetch call in my node app, but somehow the server doesn't respond at all to my request. Not sure why is that happening. The copied request contains  my session id as well so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to submit the body as parameter with the .continue() function call:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', async (request) => {
  if (request.resourceType() === 'image') {
    return request.abort();
  }
  if (request.url().indexOf('query') > -1) {
    for (let pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < 100; pageNumber++) {
      // data manipulation here...
      // maybe make a new request here or fetch(request.clone())?
      // const request2 = new Request(request.url(), {
      //   method: 'POST',
      //   postData: 'key1=value1&key2=value2',
      //   headers: {
      //     ...request.headers(),
      //    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' // replace headers
      //   }
      // });
    }
    // send manipulated method, headers or body.
    return request.continue({
      method: 'POST',
      postData: 'key1=value1&key2=value2',
      headers: {
        ...request.headers(),
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' // replace headers
      }
    });
  }
  request.continue(); // send request without manipulation.
});

page.on('response', async (response) => {
  try {
    const body = await response.text();
    console.log('response body:', body);
  } catch {
    console.log('response body error!');
  }
});
```

you might gain some insight by looking at the puppeteer tests:
[requestinterception.spec.ts](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/test/requestinterception.spec.ts)